# How to convert and download markdown text as a pdf report in Streamlit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, markdown, streamlit

I have markdown text generated in Streamlit as below.

```
st_md = '''
<b>compare mongodb to other no sql databases</b><br><br><b>Uploaded Files: </b>[]<br><br> Here is a comparison of MongoDB to some other major NoSQL databases:

- MongoDB is a document database. It stores data in flexible JSON-like documents rather than rows and columns like an RDBMS. Other document databases include CouchDB and Amazon DocumentDB.


In summary, MongoDB strikes a balance between the flexibility of document storage, rich functionality like secondary indexes and aggregations, and scalability via horizontal sharding that makes it a popular choice among many NoSQL databases today.<br><br><b>advantages and disadvantages of mongodb to other no sql ds</b><br><br><b>Uploaded Files: </b>[]<br><br> Here are some key advantages and disadvantages of MongoDB compared to other NoSQL databases:

Advantages:

- Flexible data model using documents to represent objects with dynamic schemas. More flexible than columnar databases that require predefined schemas.

- Index on any attribute for faster queries and retrieval compared to key-value stores.


Disadvantages:

- Less ACID compliance and transactions than traditional SQL databases.

- No declarative query language like SQL. Query syntax can be complex for some use cases.

So in summary, MongoDB provides a flexible document data model with rich functionality leading to faster reads and more expressiveness compared to simple key-value stores, but lacks some features database specialists may require. Scaling and performance is generally easier than traditional SQL databases.<br><br>
'''
```

I would like to download the content of `st_md` into a pdf file. I tried using the download_button but receive an error that the pdf file is damaged. What am I missing?

```
st.download_button(
    label="Download data as pdf",
    data=st_md,
    file_name='test.pdf',
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion from @Chathura Abeywickrama, I converted my markdown content to pdf using the below:

```
html = markdown2.markdown(st_md)
pdfkit.from_string(html, 'example.pdf')
```

Then use the generated pdf file in download_button

```
with open("example.pdf", "rb") as f:
    st.download_button("Download Conversation", f, f"example.pdf")
```

Comment: Can you give the whole script please!!

Answer (score 0):

The st.download_button function is designed to download files, but it may not handle the conversion of Markdown text to PDF directly. To achieve your goal, you can use the reportlab library to convert the Markdown text to a PDF file.

```
import streamlit as st
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from io import BytesIO
import base64

# Your markdown text
st_md = '''
# Your Markdown content
'''

# Function to convert Markdown to PDF
def markdown_to_pdf(markdown_text):
    buffer = BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer, pagesize=letter)
    p.drawString(100, 800, markdown_text)  # Adjust the position as needed
    p.save()
    buffer.seek(0)
    return buffer

# Get the PDF buffer
pdf_buffer = markdown_to_pdf(st_md)

# Display the download button
st.download_button(
    label="Download data as pdf",
    data=pdf_buffer,
    file_name='test.pdf',
)

# Optional: Display the PDF content in Streamlit
st.image(pdf_buffer, format='pdf')

# Close the buffer to free up resources
pdf_buffer.close()
```

Comment: Above code creates a blank pdf report. I used the st_md variable posted in the original question.